# Почему в данном примере функция вернула значение None?

Tags: python, функции

```
def foo(a):
    if a == 1000:
        return a
    a+=1
    foo(a)

a = foo(a)

print(a)
```

Прошу ответьте почему в данной ситуации будет None

Почему a не равно 1000?

Comment: Вкратце - потому что результат рекурсивного вызова вы не возвращаете через return, и вообще никак не используете.

Comment: `a = foo(a)` NameError: name 'a' is not defined. Что здесь имели в виду?

Comment: @maestro, очевидно, параметром должно быть целое число меньше (или равное) 1000, иначе рекурсия будет бесконечной. Результат по задумке видимо всегда должен быть 1000 (если добавить отсутствующий return)